# pandas.DataFrame with dict-like data in columns

Tags: python, pandas

Using `pandas`, I'm trying to improve the performace of  the processing of some logging data which I had previously done myself in Python lists, which eventually got very slow with increasing amounts of data.

Said data comes as a json file which looks something like in the following example. It's an array of *event*s, where each event is an object and has a *timestamp*, a *type* name and some *data* and *meta* info:

```
[
    {
        "timestamp": 1532334284.943328, 
        "type": "TEST_RESULT",
        "meta": {"name": "test_xyz", "param": 1.5},
        "data": {"value": 100.0, "success": true},    
    },
    {
        "timestamp": 1532334285.943328, 
        "type": "TEST_RESULT",
        "meta": {"name": "test_xyz", "param": 2.0},
        "data": {"value": 200.0, "success": true},    
    },
    {
        "timestamp": 1532334286.943328, 
        "type": "TEST_RESULT",
        "meta": {"name": "test_xyz", "param": 1.5},
        "data": {"value": 300.0, "success": false},    
    }     
]
```

First of, I used `pd.read_json` to put the data into a `pandas.DataFrame`, which results in:

```
In [50]:data
Out[50]: 
                                 data                                meta  \
0   {'value': 100.0, 'success': True}  {'name': 'test_xyz', 'param': 1.5}   
1   {'value': 200.0, 'success': True}  {'name': 'test_xyz', 'param': 2.0}   
2  {'value': 300.0, 'success': False}  {'name': 'test_xyz', 'param': 1.5}   

      timestamp         type  
0  1.532334e+09  TEST_RESULT  
1  1.532334e+09  TEST_RESULT  
2  1.532334e+09  TEST_RESULT
```

While filtering/grouping over the *type* field works, the problem is that I cannot figure out a way to do the same over what's in the *meta* and *data* dictionaries. For example:

```
data.groupby(data.meta).all()
```

results in an empty DataFrame where I'd expected to see 2 different rows, since there are 2 different (unique) objects in meta column. I figured this has to do with the objects being (unhashable) Dictionaries, which is why

```
data.meta.unique()
```

leads to

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

But then again, what would be a generic solution for this which enables me to

- groupby equal *meta* values
- have different attributes in each *meta* object, i.e. no direct way to cast them into separate DataFrame columns
- access and filter by the individual scalars inside *meta* and *data* easily

I've thought about converting those columns to `collections.namedtuple`s explicitly. At least this solves the problem of hashability with dicts. But it seems quite expensive to do it for every row at load time. Also, filtering data as with real DataFrame columns still does not work - I'd still like to be able to do

```
subset = data[data.meta.name == "test_xyz"]
```

Is there a general recipe how to use `pandas` for this kind of dynamic-length column / 3D data?

Comment: `dict` are not hashable because they are mutable. If you transform them to be `frozenset(d.items())` instead, you'll be able to hash and consequently group your df

Comment: Although it's rather slow IMO, you could create new columns from the column of dictionaries using `.apply(pd.Series)`

Comment: @RafaelC How would you extract certain keys (like `name`) from the `frozenset` later on? Or filter by it?